# General Relativity and the effect of mass on time

Tags: general-relativity, mass, time, big-bang

My question is related to the first page of [this article regarding the big bang theory](http://science.howstuffworks.com/dictionary/astronomy-terms/before-big-bang.htm) and refers to this specific sentence:

> *Armed with the best physics of the 20th century, Albert Einstein came to very similar conclusions with his theory of relativity. Just consider the effect of mass on time. A planet's hefty mass warps time -- making time run a tiny bit slower for a human on Earth's surface than a satellite in orbit. The difference is too small to notice, but time even runs more slowly for someone standing next to a large boulder than it does for a person standing alone in a field. The pre-big bang singularity possessed all the mass in the universe, effectively bringing time to a standstill.*

Considering that, here is my question: Does time actually run slower for a human standing next to a boulder? How does that work and how/where can I find out more?

Comment: "The pre-big bang singularity possessed all the mass in the universe, effectively bringing time to a standstill." This is total nonsense, so I wouldn't trust the article too much.

Comment: I would trust Wikipedia articles much more than "HowStuffWorks"...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_general_relativity

Comment: possible duplicate of [The bigger the mass, the more time slows down. Why is this?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52034/)

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed. According to general relativity, time is affected by gravity; even the very small amount of gravity that is produced by a boulder has some effect on the passage of time. I will note that just being on Earth is going to have much more of an effect on the passage of time than whether or not a boulder is present. Even so, the change by the Earth's gravity is negligible.

I don't really know of anything to read on specifically something like this without just going into relativity, but there is [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) that goes over it which isn't very long.