How can you safely enter a black hole?
In a hard science fiction novel, suppose we want our heroes to enter a black hole. What laws of physics could we tweak to make it theoretically possible, albeit a technological feat?

You get ripped apart by tidal force 100 km from a small BH (a few solar masses). See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208 You could safely cross the EH (event horizon) of a SMBH. But of course, you can't escape or send out any info.

What laws of physics could we tweak… Questions about the laws of physics are on-topic. Questions about “tweaking” the laws of physics are off-topic.

Why do you want to kill your heroes?

@Ghoster That depends. It's ok to tweak a law in a thought experiment if it helps you understand that law. But if you're just blatantly disregarding some law of physics, then it's off-topic under our "non-mainstream" policy.

You can perhaps take a few cues from the later chapters of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s_End

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187917/2451 and links therein.

@Ghoster can't the heroes avoid the singularity in a rotating black hole?

@PM2Ring “if you're just blatantly disregarding some law of physics, then it's off-topic” - Then the Hawking radiation is off-topic since it blatantly disregards the equivalence principle and/or unitarity in the Information Paradox.

Classically you can safely enter a supermassive black hole without being ripped apart until deeper inside. However, despite the overwhelming propaganda, the horizon being crossable is not a fact, but an assumption. If it is not, then your time and existence ends at the horizon. The quantum approach also suggests the same that you are destroyed at the horizon by something like the farewall singularity.
